# Parse Platform iOS. Unable to add relation

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have two parse classes with a relation between them:

```
class FeedPost:PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    @NSManaged var likedBy:PFRelation<PFUser>
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "FeedPost"
    }
}

extension PFUser {
    @NSManaged var likedPosts:PFRelation<FeedPost>
}
```

I'm trying to create a relation between the two objects when the user likes a post with the following code:

```
    if let currentUser = PFUser.current() {
        let likeQuery = post.likedBy.query()
        likeQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (users, error) in
            if let users = users {
                if !users.contains(where: {$0.objectId == currentUser.objectId}) {
                    post.likeCount += 1
                    post.likedBy.add(currentUser)
                    currentUser.likedPosts.add(post)
                    ParseNetworkQuery.shared.bulkSaveObjects(objects: [currentUser,post]) { (done) in
                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

The error points to the following line in the PFRelation.m file, specifically on the dispatch_sync line:

```
- (void)_addKnownObject:(PFObject *)object {
dispatch_sync(_stateAccessQueue, ^{
    [self.state.knownObjects addObject:object];
});
}
```

I've tried "pre-adding" the relations to both classes in the data browser. When this is done the error happens. If I remove the relations in the data browser, and let the code generate them itself when it runs, nothing happens. The columns are not created, and the "likeQuery" never executes. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does the likeCount get updated?

Comment: no it does not in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code that finally ended up working. It would seem I have to use relation(forKey: ), as getting the relation directly from the object never worked.

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.current() {
        let likedByRelation = self.relation(forKey: "likedBy")
        let query = likedByRelation.query()
        if let objectId = currentUser.objectId {
            query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectId)
            query.getFirstObjectInBackground { (object, error) in
                if object == nil {
                    view.showAlert(title: "Already Liked", message: "You've already liked this post.")
                } else {
                    self.likeCount += 1
                    likedByRelation.add(currentUser)
                    self.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
                        completion()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```